# Python: count headers in a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to now the numbers of headers my csv file contains (between 0 and ~50). The file itself is huge (so not reading the complete file for this is mandatory) and contains numerical data.
I know that csv.Sniffer has a has_header() function, but that can only detect 1 header.
One idea I had is to recursivly call the has_header funcion (supposing it detects the first header) and then counting the recursions. I am sure though, there is a much smarter way.

Googling was kind of a pain, since no matter what you search, if it includes "count" and "csv" at some point, you get all the "count rows in csv" results :D

Clarification:
With number of headers I mean number of rows containing information which is not data. There is no general rule for the headers (could be text, floats, or white spaces) and it may be a single line of text. The data itself however is only floats. For me this was super clear, because I've been working with these files for a long time, but forgot this isn't the normal case.

I hoped there was a easy and smart builtin function from Numpy or Pandas, but it doesn't seem so.

Inspired by the comments so far, I think my best bet is to

- read 100 lines
- count number of separators in each line
- determine most common number of separators per line
- Coming from the end of 100 lines, find first line with different amount of separators, or isn't floats. That line is the last header line.

Comment: what do you mean by number of headers? Do you mean your file has more than 1 row with headers? Or do you mean the number of columns?

Comment: If you can articulate rules for how to determine the difference e.g. by describing the data types or expected value ranges, writing a Python script to implement those heuristics should be trivial. Can you come up with constaints like "headers should never contain spaces" or "the third and eighth columns should contain only numbers"? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: (However, "please write Python code for me" is not an acceptable question on Stack Overflow, so perhaps then think about what your actual question about that you want to ask.)

Comment: Yes, probably need to know what you mean by headers because in a typical csv file that is just the first row of the file (i.e., containing a comma-separated list of column names).

Comment: Please remember to vote on the answers and accept the best solution. See also: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Hi, I've clarified the situation in the my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sketch for finding the first line which matches a particular criterion. For demo purposes, I use the criterion "there are empty fields":

```
import csv

with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as handle:
    for lineno, fields in enumerate(csv.reader(handle), 1):
        if "" in fields:
             print(lineno-1)
             break
```

You'd update it to look for something which makes sense for your data, like perhaps "third and eight fields contain numbers":

```
        try:
            float(fields[2])
            float(fields[7])
            print(lineno-1)
            break
        except ValueError:
            continue
```

(notice how the list `fields` is indexed starting at zero, so the first field is `fields[0]` and the third is `fields[2]`), or perhaps a more sophisticated model where the first line contains no empty fields, successive lines contain more and more empty fields, and then the first data line contains fewer empty fields:

```
    maxempty = 0
    for lineno, fields in numerate(csv.reader(handle), 1):
        empty = fields.count("")
        if empty > maxempty:
            maxempty = empty
        elif empty < maxempty:
            print(lineno-1)
            break
```

We simply print the line number of the last header line, since your question asks how many there are. Perhaps printing or returning the number of the first data line would make more sense in some scenarios.

This code doesn't use Pandas at all, just the regular `csv` module from the Python standard library. It stops reading when you hit `break` so it doesn't matter for performance how many lines there are after that (though if you need to experiment or debug, maybe create a smaller file with only, say, the first 200 lines of your real file).

Comment: Thanks! This is quite helpfull! The problem is only, that I don't really have any general rule for my data, only that the data is flaots, and the headers can be anything, see the update to my question.

Comment: Then simply "contains something which isn't a `float` as already covered here should work fine, I imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) to search for lines that have 2 or more letters in a row. Two is used instead of one, to not count as header scientific notation (e.g., `1.0e5`).

```
# In the shell, create a test file:
# echo "foo,bar\nbaz,bletch\n1e4,2.0\n2E5,2" > in_file.csv

import re
num_header_lines = 0
for line in open('in_file.csv'):
    if re.search('[A-Za-z]{2,}', line):
        # count the header here
        num_header_lines += 1
    else:
        break
print(num_header_lines)
# 2
```

Comment: This assumes that the data contains no text fields at all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that you could get the first line of the csv file and then split  it by a ",". That will return an array with all the headers in it. Now you can just count them with len.

Comment: This is a sensible answer. You could improve it with a sample of code as well as making sure to point out that column headers must of course not have commas in them (e.g., those poor csv's that have headers such as this one: `"FirstName, LastName", Age", "Gender", "Enrolled"` Thanks for contributing and keep coding!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, I clarified the situation in my question. Thanks for your advice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', index_col=0)

num_rows, num_cols = df.shape
```

Since I see you're worried about file size, breaking the file into chunks would work:

```
chunk_size = 10000

df = pd.read_csv(in_path,sep=separator,chunksize=chunk_size, 
                    low_memory=False)
```

I think you might get a variable number of rows if you read the df chunk by chunk but if you're only interested in number of columns this would work easily.

You could also look into [dask.dataframe](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html)

Answer (score -1):

This only reads first line of csv

```
import csv

with open('ornek.csv', newline='') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  row1 = next(reader)
sizeOfHeader = len(row1)
```

Comment: Since the file is "huge" it is probably not ideal to read the entire file into a dataframe in order to get the headers.

Comment: @topsail question is not clear to understand. I updated the code. Thx.

Comment: You seem to be speculating that the OP is actually trying to find how many columns there are in the file. They are asking about rows, though, and parts of the problem description don't make any sense for a question about columns.

Comment: @B. Ozen Good try anyway. I hesitated to suggest any real answers for the same reason give by tripleee in the previous comment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).